# parseFloat in jquery is not picking each decimal value

Tags: jquery, parsefloat

```
    <table style="width:40%; float: left">
        <tr>
            <th>SWG</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Size in MM</th>
            <th>Size in INCH</th>
            <th style="display:"></th>
        </tr>
<tr id="43 kacha">
            <td contenteditable>43.5</td>
            <td contenteditable>43 kacha</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.088</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0034</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="43 kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="43">
            <td contenteditable>43.0</td>
            <td contenteditable>43</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.092</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0036</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="43"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="42 kacha">
            <td contenteditable>42.5</td>
            <td contenteditable>42 kacha</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.095</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0038</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="42 kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="42">
            <td contenteditable>42.0</td>
            <td contenteditable>42</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.102</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0040</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="42"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="41 kacha">
            <td contenteditable>41.5</td>
            <td contenteditable>41 kacha</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.107</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0042</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="41 kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="40 kacha">
            <td contenteditable>40.5</td>
            <td contenteditable>40 kacha</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.117</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0046</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="40 kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="40">
            <td contenteditable>40.0</td>
            <td contenteditable>40</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.122</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0044</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="40"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="39 kacha">
            <td contenteditable>39.5</td>
            <td contenteditable>39 kacha</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.127</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0050</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="39 kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="39">
            <td contenteditable>39.0</td>
            <td contenteditable>39</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.132</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0052</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="39"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="38 kacha">
            <td contenteditable>38.5</td>
            <td contenteditable>38 kacha</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.145</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0056</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="38 kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="150">
            <td contenteditable>38.0</td>
            <td contenteditable>150</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.152</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0060</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="150"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="180">
            <td contenteditable>37.5</td>
            <td contenteditable>180</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.180</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0071</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="180"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="190">
            <td contenteditable>36.0</td>
            <td contenteditable>190</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.190</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0076</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="190"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="224">
            <td contenteditable>35.5</td>
            <td contenteditable>224</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.224</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0088</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="224"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="215">
            <td contenteditable>35.0</td>
            <td contenteditable>215</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.215</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0085</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="215"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="240">
            <td contenteditable>33.5</td>
            <td contenteditable>240</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.240</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0095</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="240"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr><tr id="250">
            <td contenteditable>33.0</td>
            <td contenteditable>250</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.254</td>
            <td contenteditable>0.0100</td>
            <td><button id="edit_entry" value="250"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
        </tr></table>       <span id="err" style="float: left"></span>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("button#edit_entry").click(function(){
                        var size = this.value;
                        var id = parseFloat($('tr#'+size+' td').eq(0).text(),10);
                        var size_mm = parseFloat($('tr#'+size+' td').eq(2).text(),10);
                        var size_inch = parseFloat($('tr#'+size+' td').eq(3).text(),10);
                        $("#err").html(id);                                 
                    }); 
                }); 
        </script>
```

in the above table,
Each table row has 4 td,
on selecting the button associated with each tr, values of td of that row is meant to be selected/stored

but
values like

```
43.5 , 0.088 , 0.0034 ; 
42.5 , 0.095 , 0.0038 ;
41.5 , ... ;
40.5 , ... ;
39.5 , ... ;
38.5 , ... ;

its shows "Nan"
```

and for the rest of the TR, its showing the exact values,

My requirement is to pick the values and send them through AJAX to database in case of UPDATION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ids with space - `38 kacha` etc, which don't evaluate to a correct selector in your click function.

One way resolve this is to use dash separated ids `38-kacha` like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button#edit_entry").click(function() {
    var size = this.value;
    var id = parseFloat($('tr#' + size + ' td').eq(0).text(), 10);
    var size_mm = parseFloat($('tr#' + size + ' td').eq(2).text(), 10);
    var size_inch = parseFloat($('tr#' + size + ' td').eq(3).text(), 10);
    $("#err").html(id);
    
    console.log(size, id, size_mm, size_inch)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <th>SWG</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Size in MM</th>
    <th>Size in INCH</th>
    <th style="display:"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="43-kacha">
    <td contenteditable>43.5</td>
    <td contenteditable>43 kacha</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.088</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0034</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="43-kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="43">
    <td contenteditable>43.0</td>
    <td contenteditable>43</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.092</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0036</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="43"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="42-kacha">
    <td contenteditable>42.5</td>
    <td contenteditable>42 kacha</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.095</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0038</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="42-kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="42">
    <td contenteditable>42.0</td>
    <td contenteditable>42</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.102</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0040</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="42"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="41-kacha">
    <td contenteditable>41.5</td>
    <td contenteditable>41 kacha</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.107</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0042</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="41-kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="40-kacha">
    <td contenteditable>40.5</td>
    <td contenteditable>40 kacha</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.117</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0046</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="40-kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="40">
    <td contenteditable>40.0</td>
    <td contenteditable>40</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.122</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0044</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="40"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="39-kacha">
    <td contenteditable>39.5</td>
    <td contenteditable>39 kacha</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.127</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0050</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="39-kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="39">
    <td contenteditable>39.0</td>
    <td contenteditable>39</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.132</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0052</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="39"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="38-kacha">
    <td contenteditable>38.5</td>
    <td contenteditable>38 kacha</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.145</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0056</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="38-kacha"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="150">
    <td contenteditable>38.0</td>
    <td contenteditable>150</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.152</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0060</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="150"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="180">
    <td contenteditable>37.5</td>
    <td contenteditable>180</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.180</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0071</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="180"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="190">
    <td contenteditable>36.0</td>
    <td contenteditable>190</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.190</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0076</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="190"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="224">
    <td contenteditable>35.5</td>
    <td contenteditable>224</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.224</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0088</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="224"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="215">
    <td contenteditable>35.0</td>
    <td contenteditable>215</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.215</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0085</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="215"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="240">
    <td contenteditable>33.5</td>
    <td contenteditable>240</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.240</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0095</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="240"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="250">
    <td contenteditable>33.0</td>
    <td contenteditable>250</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.254</td>
    <td contenteditable>0.0100</td>
    <td><button id="edit_entry" value="250"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"></button></td>
  </tr>
</table> 
<span id="err"></span>
```